# Query parents which have child in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

So, I'm struggling in the following situation:

Consider the models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class B(models.Model):
    a_models = models.ForeignKey('A', related_name='b_models')
    bar = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class bChild(B):
    bla = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

if I have an instance of A, a_instance, and I want to retrieve all the instances of class B which have a relation with it, I can use

```
all_b_models = a_instance.b_models.all()
```

My question is: what if I want to retrieve only the ones which also have bChilds:

```
all_bChild_models = a_instance.b_models.filter(???)
```

what should I put in "???"?

I'm not finding any documentation to this. One thing I think works is to use:

```
??? = pk__in=bChild.objects.all().values_list('pk')
```

However, since django creates an implicit backward relationship for Multi-table inheritance, I was wondering if there is a simpler query.

Thanks,
Jorge

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured it out by myself.

Apparently, django considers that pk is null if the model does not have a child.

So, one can use:

```
all_bChild_models = a_instance.b_models.filter(bchild__pk__isnull=False)
```

this will return all the b models which have a bChild model pointing at it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you want to fetch bChild object only via A instance when you could simply do this:

```
result = bChild.objects.filter(a_models = a)
```

Your approach wouldn't work you need a flat list to filter by pk:

```
all_bChild_models = a_instance.b_models.filter(pk__in = bChild.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew about "a_models" in filtering... In anycase, can you reformulate the first sentence? I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Sorry my bad..I meant to ask you why do you want to make the query on the a_instance directly when you can easily make it on the bChild table directly.